# .bash_history file has no timestamp

Tags: bash, timestamp

The /home/foo/.bash_history files contains no timestamp.
The root's .bash_history file has a timestamp.

How can I enable the timestamping in the users files?

BR
Christian

Comment: Thx a lot. I  insert the option into "/etc/profile" to enable this for all users

Answer (score 1):

You can define variable HISTTIMEFORMAT to time format (see [strftime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime)):

Add next linea ~/.profile:

```
      export  HISTTIMEFORMAT=%F
```

From this point all history have time